# Find an orthonormal set of three eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal

this is a practice problem that I'm struggling to find the right approach for. It only has 2 eigenvalues, shouldn't it have 3 since it's a 3x3 matrix?

[image]

Comment: The identity matrix $I$ has only one eigenvalue.

Comment: One of the values is repeated. The identity matrix has one eigenvalue (1) but is repeated 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eigenspace with respect to one of the two eigenvectors will be two-dimensional, so you can pick two out of your three vectors from there.

For illustration, consider the $3\times 3$ unit matrix. It has a single eigenvalue, which is 1. But *any* vector is an eigenvector.